# WebView as Item in GridView is taking over ItemClick event in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using a WebView as an item in a GridView in UWP. The purpose of this app is to display Svg files that can be later edited by a user.

**History**
The choice for a WebView instead of an `SvgImageSource` is because the quality of the Svgs is 100% (no pixels), so after a many failed attempts to get smooth images with Win2D I finally went for what I believe is the only way to render Svg natively, namely a `WebView`. As a side note, our Svgs are made of only  paths and rendering a Xaml path from the Svgs slowed down the performance significantly already for one svg file (circa 300kb), so that is not an option unfortunately. So back to `WebView`:

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="SvgThumbnailItemTemplate" x:DataType="inkWorkPage:SvgThumbnail">
                <WebView Source="{x:Bind UriSource}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
  </DataTemplate>
```

and the `GridView`

```
  <GridView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind SvgImages}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SvgThumbnailItemTemplate}"
              ItemClick="SvgImagesGridView_ItemClick"/>
```

What happens is that each Svg file is loaded in its WebView and displays without problems, but I can only click once on an Item (the event gets fired), but the selection stays on this item and I can no longer click on any item.

I suspect the `WebView` to take over some events through bubbling or the like, but how can I solve this?

ps: I am aware that `WebView` in a `GridView` is perhaps too much as I am looking only at displaying proper images but that is the only way to display native Svg that I can achieve now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `Border` that spans over the `WebView` makes the `GridViewItem` receive focus and becomes clickable. So the `DataTemplate` becomes

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DisplayName}"/>
        <WebView Source="{x:Bind UriSource}" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Border Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```

Using Win2D to render SVG is not recommended as of today as it turns out to be much less performant than a WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the WebViewImageBrush, rendering the webview to an image, or use a Win2D to render the SVG.  Much more performant.  You can also try setting the WebView.IsHitTestVisible = false;

Comment: OK for Win2D SVG which I can try out, but I do not see how to bind to the CanvasControl in this case? https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Svg_CanvasSvgDocument.htm . HitTestVisible did not work

Comment: OK I have a working sample by x:bin to methods in the Item, I will test the performance and see how it works. It seems too that Svg in Win2D may not support all attributes. To follow.